# Change "Transaction log directory" In WAS 8.5 Using wsadmin

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

I need to make a few changes to the "Transaction service" section of a bunch of WebSphere application servers. I was hoping to script things using wsadmin.

One of the properties that I want to change is the "Transaction log directory". I tried to following tutorial:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.migration.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_mlogdirectory.html?lang=en

The problem is that my `recoveryLog` object is always empty (with a Jython value of `None`) Is there another way to change this value?

Related to this question, are there properties that I can edit using the WAS web console that I can't edit using wsadmin? I would like to change a few more "deeply nested" properties and I want to make sure that I'm not wasting my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change the log directory with the following commands:

```
serverEntryId = AdminConfig.getid("/ServerEntry:server1")
recoveryLog = AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverEntryId, "recoveryLog")
AdminConfig.modify(recoveryLog, '[[transactionLogDirectory c:/mylog]]')
AdminConfig.save()
```

Regarding your second question - everything what you can do via web console is doable via wsadmin scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gas. Unfortunately, the "recoveryLog" object still has a value of None. What version of WAS are you using? I'm using 8.5.5.1.

Comment: Do you get anything while calling:
AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverEntryId, "recoveryLog")
rl = AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverEntryId, "recoveryLog")
print AdminConfig.show(rl)

if not you may need to create recoveryLog entry using:
AdminConfig.create(serverEntry, 'recoveryLog') 

I'm on 8.5.5.1

Comment: I tried running that and got a NullPointerException. What do you mean when you ask if I've created a recoveryLog. Shouldn't it exist by default?

Comment: No, it doesn't exists, if it has default settings. However once its create, in any subsequent changes you are only modifying it.
I missed exact command to create that entry in last post, it should be like this:
AdminConfig.create('RecoveryLog', serverEntry, '[[transactionLogDirectory "c:\mylog"]]') 

You can check the command in admin console via: 'Command Assistance - View administrative scripting command for last action'

Comment: Thanks a ton Gas. So basically I need to first create a recovery log and then specify the trans log directory as a property of that.

Answer (score 0):

Gas' answer is correct, assuming that you create the trans log first using the directions in his comments. I solved this problem a little differently though using the **execellent** [WDR library](http://wdr.github.io/WDR/). Here's how I did it:

```
mySeverEntry = listConfigObjects("ServerEntry", "*TomsServer*")[0]
mySeverEntry.create("RecoveryLog", 
        transactionLogDirectory="/some/dir1"), 
        compensationLogDirectory="/some/dir2"), 
        compensationLogFileSize="5") 
save()
sync()
```

I *highly* recommend the WDR library if you're looking for a more concise, pythonic way of scripting wsadmin changes.